# rails - get url(like url_for) without raising error if not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting url like this:

```
url_for(:controller => :controller, :action => :action-name)
```

This is raising error if the route is not found.
I want it to return empty url if the route is not found.

Whats the solution ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap this with helper.
Something like:

```
def silent_url_for(options = nil)
  begin
    url_for(options)
  rescue SomeException
    ''
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you the exception ?